# Create "x" amount of html elements in template based on how many elements I have in DB

Tags: go

I need to create an html page that display all the "forums" present in the database in my .html file.
Example:

```
<body>
{{with index . 0}}
  <a href="/sID={{.Id}}">{{.Name}}<br></a>{{.Descr}}</td>
{{end}}

{{with index . 1}}
  <a href="/sID={{.Id}}">{{.Name}}<br></a>{{.Descr}}
{{end}}
</body>

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
forums := GetForumsFromDB() // return a slice of type Forum from the db
tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", forums)
}

type Forum struct {
    Id    int
    Name  string
    Descr string
}
```

But in this case I need to already know how many forums are there in the db when writing the .html file. How should I approach this? Should I pass the html into the template together with my slice? Should I use a method of Forum that return the html for every forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `range`:

```
{{range .}}
  <a href="/sID={{.Id}}">{{.Name}}<br></a>{{.Descr}}
{{end}}
```